# Properties of a smallest tournament with domination number $k$

Tags: graph-theory, directed-graphs, graph-domination

For some tournament $T$, let $\gamma(T)$ denote the cardinality of a smallest dominating set of $T$.

Denote by $f(k)$ the minimum number of vertices of a tournament $T$ having $\gamma(T) = k$.
From what I've been able to find, not much is known about $f$.
We know $f(2) = 3, f(3) = 7$ and $f(4) = 19$.  Past that we're lost.
Results from Erdos and Szekeres-Szekeres showed that 
$$(k + 1) 2^{k - 2} - 1 \leq f(k) \leq (k - 1)^2 2^{k -1} C$$

(for suitable constant $C$) some 50 years ago, and
I haven't any refinement of those bounds (except that $f(5) > 47$, showing the lower bound is not exact).

I'm interested in the structural properties of a tournament $T$ of order $f(k)$ having $\gamma(T) = k$,
but I can't find much except this paper : [Domination and irredundance in tournaments](http://ajc.maths.uq.edu.au/pdf/29/ajc_v29_p157.pdf)  and its references.
Any references that describe $T$ would be helpful.

In particular, I'm interested in the existence/non-existence of a constant $c$ that satisfies this statement for any $k$ 
(and for a large enough tournament) :

> Let $T$ be a tournament of order $f(k)$ having $\gamma(T) = k$. Then,
>   for any set $U \subseteq V(T)$ with $|U| = k - c$, there exists a set
>   $U' \subseteq V(T) \setminus U$ of cardinality $c$ such that $U \cup U'$ is a dominating set.

In other words, pick any $k - c$ vertices.  Then there's some smallest dominating set that contains them.
This doesn't hold for $c = 0$, but it makes intuitive sense that it does for $c = 1$.
However, I'm not even close to showing this is true for some constant,
neither that there there is a $c$ for which the statement holds for every $k$, but for at least 
one smallest tournament with domination number $k$.